# get event.result for a input type file in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file

The problem I have is that I am not getting the value of the result here; the code alerts `undefined`. I want to preview the image selected by user. Can someone tell me what the issue is?

```
<input type="file" name="file_name" style='display: none;' id='cover_image_90' onchange="chnageBGDynamic(this, 'Cover_Iamge_90op', '0');"/>
```

```js
function chnageBGDynamic(file_id_ch,change_bg_id,is_aled_othr){

    var files = !!file_id_ch.files ? file_id_ch.files : [];
    if (!files.length || !window.FileReader) 
        return; // no file selected, or no FileReader support
    if (/^image/.test( files[0].type)){ // only image file
        var reader = new FileReader(); // instance of the FileReader
        reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]); // read the local file            
        reader.onloadend = function(){ // set image data as background of div
            $("#"+change_bg_id).css("background-image", "url("+file_id_ch.result+")"); // here is the problem it dosent gets changed. i get a blank background and when checked by inspect element i get undefined src
            $("#"+change_bg_id).css("background-size", "cover");
        }}else{
            if(is_aled_othr =='0'){
                alert('Only Images Are Allowed to Upload '); return false;
            }else{
            $("#"+change_bg_id).css("background-image", "url(avator/icon/noticei.png)");
            $("#"+change_bg_id).css("background-size", "85%");
            $("#"+change_bg_id).css("background-repeat", "no-repeat");
            }
    }

}
```

Comment: instead of `file_id_ch.result`; could you please try `file_id_ch.files`

Comment: i have updated the question please take a look so that you may better understand what i am trying to do .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is almost correct; just need one small change:

Instead of

`$("#"+change_bg_id).css("background-image", "url("+file_id_ch.result+")");`

We need:

```
$("#"+change_bg_id).css("background-image", "url("+reader.result+")");
```

function chnageBGDynamic(file_id_ch,change_bg_id,is_aled_othr){

```
var files = !!file_id_ch.files ? file_id_ch.files : [];
if (!files.length || !window.FileReader) 
    return; // no file selected, or no FileReader support
if (/^image/.test( files[0].type)){ // only image file
    var reader = new FileReader(); // instance of the FileReader
    reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]); // read the local file            
    reader.onloadend = function(){ // set image data as background of div
        $("#"+change_bg_id).css("background-image", "url("+reader.result+")"); // here is the problem it dosent gets changed. i get a blank background and when checked by inspect element i get undefined src
        $("#"+change_bg_id).css("background-size", "cover");
    }}else{
        if(is_aled_othr =='0'){
            alert('Only Images Are Allowed to Upload '); return false;
        }else{
        $("#"+change_bg_id).css("background-image", "url(avator/icon/noticei.png)");
        $("#"+change_bg_id).css("background-size", "85%");
        $("#"+change_bg_id).css("background-repeat", "no-repeat");
        }
}

}
```

`.result` is a property of `FileReader` object and not of `input` of type `file`

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="file" name="file_name" id='cover_image_90' onchange="chnageBGDynamic(this, 'Cover_Iamge_90op', '0');"/>
<script>
    function chnageBGDynamic(file_id_ch, change_bg_id, is_aled_othr) {    
    console.log(file_id_ch.files);
    console.log(file_id_ch.value);
    console.log(change_bg_id);
}
    </script>
```

use .value to see the file name and .files which will contain all the info about the image file [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0oua0hzd/1/) and you can see the output in developer tool in console tab

Comment: please take a look at the updated question .. what i am trying to do is smiler to this but not the same... :(